# Calculating MODIS EVI feature collection but not landsat

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, landsat, feature-collection

I'm not sure why I am able to calculate the median EVI for MODIS but not for Landsat. I can see the time series of Landsat EVI values in the Inspector panel for a single pixel but when I export I get an empty csv. I also tried to do this just for Landsat Band 2 to see if the equation was the issue but this does not seem to work either.

Link to Script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fsharsid94%2FFloodplains%3Afilter%20landsat%20and%20calculate%20EVI

Asset for generating grid points: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/sharsid94/LBA_Amazon_wetland_dual-season_veg_flood_3arcsec

```
// LOAD ROI
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  -63.353386188055985,  -0.42829233109583215,
  -63.353429103400224,  -0.4353731617728937,
  -63.3454468493719,    -0.4353731617728937,
  -63.3454468493719,    -0.42829233109583215,
  -63.353386188055985,  -0.42829233109583215])
  
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(roi,{},'ROI')
// Create grid of extraction points off of an image (ie Hess raster)
var hessPoints = image.sampleRegions({
  collection: roi,
  scale: 90,
  geometries: true})
print(hessPoints)
Map.addLayer(hessPoints,{},'Grid Points');

// Bring in LANDSAT data
// Landsat 8: 2013 - Present
var mod_evi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1")
              .filterDate('2017-01-01','2018-01-01')
              .map(function(img) {return img.clip(roi)})

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT")
              .filterDate('2017-01-01','2018-01-01')
              .map(function(img) {return img.clip(roi)})


var cloudlessEVI = l8.map(function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var mask = cloud.lte(10);
  //var threshold = image.select('B4').lte(12000)
  //var mask = threshold.updateMask(threshold);
  //2.5 * ((B5 – B4) / (B5 + 6 * B4 – 7.5 * B2 + 1))
  var evi = image.expression('2.5*((B5-B4)/(B5+(6*B4)-(7.5*B2)+1))', {
      'B6': image.select('B6'),  //SWIR
      'B5': image.select('B5'),  //NIR
      'B4': image.select('B4'),  //RED
      'B2': image.select('B2')}) //BLUE
      .rename('EVI'); 
  return image.addBands(evi).updateMask(mask);
});

// Reducer function to Extract Pixels at points
var reducerEVI = function(image) {
  var median = image.reduceRegions({
    collection: hessPoints,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    scale: 90,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326'});
  return median
    .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['median']))
    .map(function(feature) {
      return feature.set({
          'imgID': image.id(),
          'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})})};


//MODIS EVI
var evi = mod_evi.select('EVI')
var evi_fc = evi.map(reducerEVI)
print(evi_fc.first(),'MODIS EVI')

//Landsat B2
var evi_b2 = cloudlessEVI.select('B2')
var evi_fc_b2 = evi_b2.map(reducerEVI)
print(evi_fc_b2.first(),'B2')

//Landsat EVI
var evi = cloudlessEVI.select('EVI')
var evi_fc = evi.map(reducerEVI)
print(evi_fc.first(),'Cloudless EVI')

Map.addLayer(cloudlessEVI.select('EVI'),{min: -1,max: 2,palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF']},'Cloudless EVI')

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: evi_fc,
    description: 'C1_L8_evi_TS_90_2017',
    folder: 'fp_disturbance',
    fileNamePrefix: 'C1_L8_evi_TS_90_2017',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

Comment: Please, fix the link: `Repository users/sharsid94/Floodplains does not exist.`

Comment: Hello, thank you for letting me know. I have made the repository readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you're clipping every image in the collection with the ROI, regardless of whether it intersects the ROI or not.  That's 147,700 images, when in fact there's only 19 images that actually intersect your ROI.  Yes, you're filtering off the ones that are null, but only after spending all that time doing 147,000 things you didn't need to do.

Second, your final result, `evi_fc` is in fact a collection of collections (because you're mapping reduceRegions over the images, and each individual result is a collection).  You can't export a collection of collections, you need to `flatten` it first.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a little confused about why clipping would be an issue. I reran it without the clipping line and it still seems to take a while to process. Should I perform another operation instead of clipping?